# how to import icons from other packages in java

Tags: java, import, icons, jlabel

Ok so I use use this code to import an icon from the same file that the class is in and assign it a `JLabel`,

```
JLabel label1;
Icon iron_ore = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("icon_ore"));
label1 = new JLabel(iron_ore);
```

But what code do I have to add if I want to put the icon in a file different from witch the class is in? Thank you.

Comment: Please be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is in the package `foo.bar.baz`, you use

```
getClass().getResource("/foo/bar/baz/the-icon.png")
```

as explained in the javadoc, of course.